# Rails 4 - Factorize and respect MVC for a complex conditional view on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails 4 app.

Basic models are Users and Deals.
Each user can participate in many deals and I count the number of times he participated in each deal (when they're signed  in).
Deals and user have a many to many relaitons via a UserDeal tables.

I tried putting the code in a controller or model method but it failed so I'm stuck with the code below which is working but I feel it should be put somewhere else in a controller, a model or a concern (and not like this as in the view).

Basically on this homepage, I display a list of current deals and **for each deal** I write on its card:

- if user is signed-in: the number of time the user has participated in the deal
- if user is not signed-in:  a sentence like 'who are you ? come on go participate on this deal'

Important: in the UserDeal table: a userdeal line appears for deal= 2 and user id= 4 only when the user id = 4 goes on the page of deal=2 and does something. Before this line/object does NOT exist.

**Homepage view (the block with the list of cards)**

```
<% @deals.each do |deal| %>

    <li class="card <%= deal.id %>">
      <%=  @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal    
      # User is signed-in 
      if user_signed_in?
        @userdeal = UserDeal.where('user_id = ? AND deal_id = ?', current_user.id, deal.id).take 
        if @userdeal.nil?
          @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal = 'you never did anything in this deal'
        # if user signed in and has participated in the deal
        else
          @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal =  @userdeal.nb_participations_past_week - @userdeal.nb_participations_two_weeks_ago
        end 

      # user is an anonymous visitor
      else  
        @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal = 'who are you ? come on go participate on this deal'
      end    

       %>

    <div class="card-content" id="operation_<%= deal.id %>"> 
       here is the content of the card: <%= deal.content %>

    </li>
<% end %>
```

**Models**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :user_deals,           dependent:  :destroy
  has_many   :users,                through:    :user_deals  
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_deals           
  has_many :deals,                through: :user_deals
end
class UserDeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user,         :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  belongs_to :deal,         :foreign_key => 'deal_id'
end
```

**My question is : where should I put the code below that is today all in the view to respect MVC and be Rails-y (reusable, modular code...)?** I tried putting them in Deal or User model or controller but did not work. I only works today when they're in side the view.

```
<%=  @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal    
          # User is signed-in 
          if user_signed_in?
            @userdeal = UserDeal.where('user_id = ? AND deal_id = ?', current_user.id, deal.id).take 
            if @userdeal.nil?
              @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal = 'you never did anything in this deal'
            # if user signed in and has participated in the deal
            else
              @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal =  @userdeal.nb_participations_past_week - @userdeal.nb_participations_two_weeks_ago
            end 

          # user is an anonymous visitor
          else  
            @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal = 'who are you ? come on go participate on this deal'
          end    

           %>
```

**HomepageController**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home    
    @deals = deals.featured_on_hp     
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # home.html.erb
      format.json { render json:  @deals }
      format.xml  { render xml:   @deals }
    end
  end
end
```

**Deal model**

```
scope :featured_on_hp, -> { order(deal_end_date: :asc) }
```

**EDIT**

More details as requested in the comments.

For example if I add the block of code inside the Homepagecontroller I get this

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home    
    @deals = deals.featured_on_hp

# User is signed-in 
 if user_signed_in?
     @userdeal = UserDeal.where('user_id = ? AND deal_id = ?', current_user.id, deal.id).take 
      if @userdeal.nil?
         @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal = 'you never did anything in this deal'
      # if user signed in and has participated in the deal
      else
         @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal =  @userdeal.nb_participations_past_week - @userdeal.nb_participations_two_weeks_ago
      end 

# user is an anonymous visitor
else  
  @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal = 'who are you ? come on go participate on this deal'
end 


 respond_to do |format|
    format.html # home.html.erb
    format.json { render json:  @deals }
    format.xml  { render xml:   @deals }
  end
end
end
```

and I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `deal' for #<HomepageController:0x00xxxxxxx>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: edited the question => see the end

Comment: I believe it can be simplified , and put to decorator

Comment: a decorator is like a concern?

Comment: decorator is like a view helper, but much obvious and simpler: see draper gem

Comment: I have a User, a Deal and a UserDeal tables, model and controllers but each time Put it outside the View I have an issue. for example if i put it inside the Homepage controller, it throws an error like "undefined local variable or method `deal' for #<HomepageController:0x007fa61d0ed768> beacause the homepage has ALL/many deals...

Comment: my first problem is not simplicity (which would not hurt though): it's to know how to make it work without having the whole code in the VIew. Because it's a homepage with many deals, and it refers to multiple tables (user, deals and userdeals), it does not work if I place it inside of of the controllers/models.

Comment: Show the homepage controller. What is @deal_number_of_participations_in_deal and why are you setting a variable in the view? A lot of the code in that view can be moved into the model and the controller. If you are making a db call in a view, 9 times out of 10, that should be moved into the model or controller or at the very least a helper method. If you put some scopes on the model and do the check in the controller to determine if the user is signed in or not, that view will be much simplified.

Comment: @margo will add it to my question, i know that i should be putting it inside controller o model, but in my case I did not manage to make it work except by having it inside the view. Hence my question:)

Comment: @margo added more info

Comment: the big problem is the thing I am doing involve multiples models at once. so on homepagecontroller I have '@deals...' but then if I refer to one '@deal', or '@user', then the controller does not know what they are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this line

```
@deals = deals.featured_on_hp
```

be

```
@deals = Deal.featured_on_hp
```

Since you have the deal and the user and the relationship is many_to_many you can get the user from the deal

```
current_user.deals.any?{|d| d.id == deal.id}
```

Start by simplifying the view with little steps, then you will see where you can do things differently to improve. One step would be to put the logic in the li tag into a helper method...

```
<li class="card <%= deal.id %>">
  <%= user_deal_message(@user, deal) %>
  <div class="card-content" id="operation_<%= deal.id %>"> 
     here is the content of the card: <%= deal.content %>
</li>
```

helpers/deal_helper.rb

```
module DealHelper
  def user_deal_message(user, deal)
    if user
      msg = signed_in_user_deal_message(user, deal)
    else
      msg = 'who are you ? come on go participate on this deal'
    end
    msg
  end

  def signed_in_user_deal_message(user, deal)
    user_deal = user.deals.select{|d| d.id == deal.id}
    if user_deal.any?
      user_deal_participations(user, user_deal.first)
    else
      'you never did anything in this deal'
    end
  end

  def user_deal_participations(user, deal)
    user.deals.nb_participations_past_week - user_deal.nb_participations_two_weeks_ago
  end
end
```

This can be improved on but it makes the view cleaner. Also consider using a partial. When there's alot going on on a page, partializing the view really helps maintainability, particularly when you have more than one person working on it and when you add to it.

Comment: I'm testing it. when you use 'if user', this is similar (but shorter) than me checking via devise if user_signed_in?. it also works to check if a user is signed in ?

Comment: I would set the user variable in the controller method e.g.  @user = user_signed_in? ? current_user : nil. Then you can check it in the view, I've updated my answer. You may have to play around with it as I don't know the full context of your view and controller.